# How to deploy ABP framework?

Tags: docker, nginx, blazor, abp

After spending a year to ABP.io framework, I have learned a lot, and I think it is a fantastic framework.

However, feels like totally undeployable, with very limited documentation on the area, specially when encryption involved. I have partly deployed it in Kubernetes and cert-manager, with reverse proxy and https termination, but with failures which I don't know how to solve.

Can you give me an example of how to containarize the ABP Blazor WebAssembly project into a Dockerfile? All I got is:

nginx.conf:

```
events { }
http {
    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
ADD . /build

WORKDIR /build/src/MyCompany.Blazor
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Collect from build to app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS app

WORKDIR /app

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build-env /build/src/MyCompany.Blazor/out/wwwroot /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN rm /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json
RUN mv /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.Staging.json /usr/share/nginx/html/appsettings.json 
COPY --from=build-env /build/src/MyCompany.Blazor/nginx.conf /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Error from WebBrowser (DevTools)

```
https://staging.mycompany.com/authentication/login-callback?code=bUTdZG45rK_dSQlmgrq9vPceUwNYlzU8vBFNWd8u0GM&state=61121e0d8b054746bbbc87a9bc56f3eb&iss=https%3A%2F%2Fauthy.staging.mycompany.com%2F 404
```

And the authserver logs give:

```
[20:04:47 INF] The authorization request was successfully extracted: {
  "client_id": "MyCompany_Blazor",
  "redirect_uri": "https://staging.mycompany.com/authentication/login-callback",
  "response_type": "code",
  "scope": "openid profile MyCompany roles email phone",
  "state": "2f8b48d9cccb47ad8f66736f3bce35f9",
  "code_challenge": "odlvY4nLp9nUdcrbzYClTQSSMtXlw9x3FNanYNYdv7Q",
  "code_challenge_method": "S256",
  "prompt": "none",
  "response_mode": "query"
}.
[20:04:47 INF] The authorization request was successfully validated.
[20:04:47 INF] Executing endpoint 'Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.Controllers.AuthorizeController.HandleAsync (Volo.Abp.OpenIddict.AspNetCore)'
```

Perhaps it is the Blazor Wasm Docker image that is not valid, some seed, or something else. Please give me support, after spending weeks with this :/ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The deployment mostly depends on your application type is being tiered (seperate authserver and http.api.host) or a monolith single deployment.

For a very simple **Dockerfile** for blazor, you can use something like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS build
COPY bin/Release/net7.0/publish/ app/
  
FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/wwwroot .
COPY /nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

**Be warned** that you need to publish your application first:
`dotnet publish -c Release -p:PublishTrimmed=false` (trimming is up to you).

And here is a sample nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  _;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;      
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

As for your error, make sure that the OpenIddict data is seeded correctly. The redirectURI is related to the Client (application) creation in the `OpenIddictDataSeedContributor`:

```cs
// Blazor Client
var blazorClientId = configurationSection["MyProjectName_Blazor:ClientId"];
if (!blazorClientId.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    var blazorRootUrl = configurationSection["MyProjectName_Blazor:RootUrl"]?.TrimEnd('/');

    await CreateApplicationAsync(
        name: blazorClientId!,
        type: OpenIddictConstants.ClientTypes.Public,
        consentType: OpenIddictConstants.ConsentTypes.Implicit,
        displayName: "Blazor Application",
        secret: null,
        grantTypes: new List<string> { OpenIddictConstants.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode, },
        scopes: commonScopes,
        redirectUri: $"{blazorRootUrl}/authentication/login-callback",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: $"{blazorRootUrl}/authentication/logout-callback",
        clientUri: blazorRootUrl,
        logoUri: "/images/clients/blazor.svg"
    );
}
```

As you notice, the `redirectUri` is generated from the `RootUrl` of the **DbMigrator** (assuming you are seeding data using it) `appsettings.json`. So, you might forgot to override it.

If you are using commercial version, there is a detailed deployment guide using **Docker Compose** at: https://docs.abp.io/en/commercial/latest/startup-templates/application/deployment-docker-compose?UI=Blazor&DB=EF&Tiered=Yes